# Binary Search text file that was put into an Array<Integer> using Java

Tags: java, binary

I'm kind of new to the whole programming thing and still get stuck. I have been working on a class assignment for the past 3 days and this is due tonight, so would REALLY appreciate any help offered.

Instructions:
You are provided a file that contains (semi-random) years from modern history with the earliest year first. Write a program that:

1. Reads in the file
2. Re-sorts it with the latest events first
3. Determines whether the founding of CMU in 1892 was considered a world historic event
4. If not so yet, add the event to a new list of events
5. Writes the new list of events to a file.

Hints:

Choosing the right search approach allows you to make insertion a lot easier.

Here is the information listed in the events.txt file:

1066
1095
1100
1206
1215
1260
1271
1273
1300
1347
1399
1438
1455
1492
1509
1513
1517
1519
1520
1522
1543
1582
1603
1605
1609
1637
1643
1664
1667
1684
1690
1721
1755
1760
1762
1764
1769
1776
1787
1789
1792
1796
1808
1815
1819
1826
1833
1842
1859
1862
1867
1876
1879
1880
1885
1893
1895
1897
1900
1903
1905
1907
1911
1913
1914
1916
1917
1918
1922
1927
1928
1929
1936
1939
1942
1945
1946
1947
1949
1950
1953
1954
1957
1959
1969
1980
1981
1989
1991

Here is one of the codes that I've got so far:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment7 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {



    System.out.println("Accessing Central Michigan University Historical Records...");
    System.out.println("Listing all CMU Historical Event Dates: ");





    Scanner file = null;
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    try {
    file = new Scanner(new File("events.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while(file.hasNext()){
    if (file.hasNextInt()) list.add(file.nextInt());
    else file.next();

        }



    {


    Collections.reverse(list);
    for (Object i: list) 
        System.out.println(i);



}
}
}
```

Any help that is offered will be GREATLY appreciated.

Here is the output I get without the last piece of code that I need to perform the binary search.

```
Accessing Central Michigan University Historical Records...
Listing all CMU Historical Event Dates: 
1991
1989
1981
1980
1969
1959
1957
1954
1953
1950
1922
```

...and so on to 1066

Entered the piece of code below to attempt the binary search but got the message "The method add(int, int) is undefined for the type Scanner" Not sure how to fix this. Like I said NEWB and I mean VERY NEW, first semester of programming w/ java.

```
int key = 1892;
int pos = Collections.binarySearch(list, key);
if (pos < 0)
file.add(-pos-1, key);
```

Comment: Show the code that doesn't work and specify the errors you're receiving.

Comment: You've posted way too much code. I'm guessing you can pinpoint some specific problems? If the problems are the errors, make sure you read them carefully (names + stack traces), and debug properly.

Comment: took the second piece of coding out since I'm more lost w/ that than the first. Also added the piece that is giving me issues. Had the piece of code that I'm having issues with placed between the while and Collections.reverse statements. Hope that helps. Thanks for the replies ^_^

Comment: Always search in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html). Consider that a binary search expects to list to be sorted (ascendingly). There is a `Collections.binarySearch` with a `Comparator<Integer>` argument and `Collections.reverseOrder`.

Comment: I tried the 'binarySearch' but not w/ the 'Comparator<Integer>'. Did end up using the 'Collections.reverse' statement. Just glad I got it done prior to being due. Thanks for all the help! ^ ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When starting a project, you should think about how to break it up into steps. For this example, I can think of two important steps: parse the input file into an array, then perform a binary search on the array to check for the value.

Since you've already gotten the first part down, you should create a new method that does the binary search portion.

Since this is an intro Java class, I would be very surprised if your professor wants you using built in methods like the `Collections.binarySearch`.

here is some pseudoish code for the method that takes in an int key and an array as parameters:

note:the array should be sorted in ascending order

```
int low = starting index
int high = last index
while(low <= high)
    int mid = current middle index
    if(key < array[mid])
        high = mid - 1
    else if(key > array[mid])
        low = mid + 1
    else return mid 
 end while
```

If `mid` is equal to the value you are looking for, then you know that date was in the list. Otherwise, it was not contained in the list.

Looking at your code:

```
do{
File f = new File("events.txt");
//Intro
System.out.println("Accessing Central Michigan University Historical Records...");
System.out.println("Searching for events that occurred during 1892...");
String [] targetDate = {"1892"};
Arrays.asList(targetDate).contains("1892");
    //If date is found, print.
    if(false){
        System.out.println("Date found in CMU Historical Records.");
        System.out.print(f);
    }
    //If date isn't found, notify user.
    else
        System.out.println("Date not found in CMU Historical Records.");
```

}

I notice a few things wrong. There's no reason to put the target date as a `String` array. After all, you are searching for an `int` so you want to keep it that way. You should call the `findDates()` method with the key and the `int` array. Your if statement is not doing what you think it is doing, either. You want to put `if(year==true)` instead of `if(true)`, or better yet, just `if(year)`

As an aside, I don't think `Scanner` has an `add()` method

It also seems you have a typo here:

```
file.add(-pos-1, key);
```

I think what you mean to say is something like this

```
file.add(list.get(pos - 1), key);
```

although, this is not necessary in this situation.

Hope this helped! ...and trust me, it gets better :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, took your advice and went back through step by step... finally got code to show but still missing things. Thanks again for the help ^ ^

Comment: not a problem. feel free to post any stack traces if you get stuck

Comment: I finally figured it out. Still had to incorperate the Collections.reverse statement to get the order needed and added a line in there to add the date where I needed it to be. I don't think my instructor cares how we do it. He's pretty laid back and encourages us to look up ways to complete the program if we need to. But anywho, I REALLY appreciate your help and going back to the step by step thing did help, so THANK YOU!!! ^ ^